# How to write simple sound recognition program

Tags: audio

I would like to write a simple program that recognizes a specific sound (simple sound like door shut).
The idea is that the input is the sound that I would like to be recognized, then the programs runs and and when it "hears" that sound again it tells the user.

The language does not really matter (this is for Proof Of Concept).
do you know about such an API in Java\ C#\ Python? (I have no experience in Sound recognition algorithms).

thanks,
Alex

Comment: Where does the sound come from? Microphone?

Comment: yeah, i plan to record it using a microphone, but for the argument i can also use some media file